# Lebesgue decomposition theorem for measure on product space

Tags: measure-theory

Let's have two measurable spaces $(X,\Sigma_X),(Y,\Sigma_Y)$ and measure $\mu$ on $(X,\Sigma_X)$ and measure $\nu$ on product space $(X\times Y,\Sigma_{X\times Y})$.

Does analogy of Lebesgue decomposition theorem still holds? By this I mean:

> Are there measures $\nu_1, \nu_2$ such that $\nu = \nu_1 + \nu_2$ and $\nu_1 \ll \mu, \nu_2 \perp \mu.$
>
> $\nu_1 \ll \mu  \overset{\text{def}}{\iff} \left(\forall A \in \Sigma_X, \,\, \mu(A) = 0 \Rightarrow \nu_1(A\times Y) = 0 \right)$
>
> $\nu_2 \perp \mu \,\overset{\text{def}}{\iff} \left( \exists A \in \Sigma_X, \, \mu(X\setminus A) = 0 , \, \nu_2(A\times Y)=0\right)$

Can we have Radon-Nikodym derivative of $\nu_1$ too?

> Is there function $f: X\times \Sigma_Y \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$? Such that $\forall A\in \Sigma_{X\times Y} \,\, \nu_1(A) = \int_X f(x,A^x) \,d\mu(x)$.
>
> $A^x  \overset{\text{def}}{=} \{ y\in Y : (x,y)\in A\}$

---

My approach using vector measures. Unfortunately my knowledge of vector measures is very sloppy, so I'm unable to fill all those gaps.

My idea is to take vector measure $\tilde \nu$ on $(X,\Sigma_X)$ and as vector space the space of all measures with finite variations on $(Y,\Sigma_Y)$. Measure $\tilde \nu$ is defined as $\tilde \nu(A)(B) = \nu(A\times B), A\in \Sigma_X, B\in \Sigma_Y$.

I guess that from measure $\tilde \nu$ we can uniquely reconstruct measure $\nu$, and we can use Lebesgue decomposition theorem for $\tilde \nu$ to obtain $\tilde \nu_1, \tilde \nu_2$, from these we can uniquely construct $\nu_1,\nu_2$

Comment: Lebesgue Decomposition Theorem and Radon-Nikodym Theorem apply to measures defined in the SAME measure spaces.  So, you may try to use them to compare/study  $\nu$ to the product measure, but not to compare  $\nu$ to  only one factor. Please, note that  Lebesgue Decomposition Theorem and Radon-Nikodym Theorem have also additional conditions (regarding $\sigma$-finiteness).

Comment: It seams to me that you missed the point of the question. I try to state analogy of Lebesgue Decomposition Theorem in the setting where you have one measure on product space and one measure only on one factor.

Comment: Your generalisation of $\perp$ seems to be somewhat broken. If $\mu \neq 0$, then $\nu_2\perp \mu$ can only hold for $\nu_2 =0$.

Comment: Ahh you are right, fixed.

Comment: The first part of the "extension" seems trivial. For any $A \in \Sigma_X$ define $\tilde \nu(A) =\nu(A\times Y)$.  Then  $\nu \ll \mu$ (in your sense) if and only if $\tilde \nu \ll \mu$ (in the usual sense). Also  $\nu \perp \mu$ (in your sense) if and only if $\tilde \nu \perp \mu$ (in the usual sense).  So the "Lebesgue decomposition" (in your sense) of $\nu$ w.r.t $\mu$ actually reduces to the Lebesgue decomposition (in the usual sense) of  $\tilde \nu$ w.r.t $\mu$.   Note that, anyway, the condition regarding $\sigma$-finetess  need to be fulfilled.

Comment: @Ramiro But how do I get decomposition of $\nu$ from decomposition of $\tilde \nu$? (note that my and yours definition of $\tilde \nu$ are different)

Comment: The way you defined "$\nu \ll \mu$"  and "$\nu \perp \mu$",  you are actually just working with the measure  $\gamma(A)= \nu(A\times Y)$.  So the decomposition you can get is the decomposition of $\gamma$.

Comment: Please, could you clarify: when you write about your approach you write about vector valued measures whose range is the space of finite variation measures. Would it be correct to say that your question is about Lebesgue Decomposition Theorem and Radon-Nikodym theorem for meausres defined in the SAME space $(X,\Sigma_X)$ BUT where one of the measures is a vector measure whose range is the space of finite variation measures ($\tilde \nu$)?